# javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Hostname xx.yy.subdomain.domain.com not verified:

Tags: android, okhttp

I connect to server xx.yy.subdomain.domain.tld, it's certificate issued to:
CN: *.subdomain.domain.tld,

subjectAltNames: [*.subdomain.domain.tld, subdomain.domain.com]
And I get
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Hostname xx.yy.subdomain.domain.com not verified instead.

Why? is xx.yy.subdomain.domain.tld is not match for *.subdomain.domain.tld ?

Answer (score 1):

In wildcard certificates, stars don't match dots. You need more subjectAltNames or a different host name.